Download File in react native
even though the permission is given my code throws permission required error
i want to save the image like when i write const granted = getPermissionAndroid(); it saves image when the permission is not given and when i write const granted = await getPermissionAndroid(); even though the permission is given it says Permission required
const onClickExportImage = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        const uri = await viewShotRef.current.capture();
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            const granted = await getPermissionAndroid(); 
        if (!granted) {
            return;
        }
    }
    const newURI = await CameraRoll.save(uri, {
        type: 'photo',
        album: 'Lukim Gather',
    });
    Toast.show(_('Saved image in gallery!'));
    setTimeout(() => {
        Linking.openURL(newURI);
    }, 1000);
    setIsOpenExport(false);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}

}, [getPermissionAndroid]);
const getPermissionAndroid = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            {
                title: _('Image export permission'),
                message: _('Your permission is required to save image'),
                buttonNegative: _('Cancel'),
                buttonPositive: _('OK'),
            },
        );
        console.log('Permission result:', granted);
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            setIsOpenExport(false);
            Toast.error(_('Permission denied!'));
            return false;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error' + err);
        return false;
    }
}, []);


Welcome to StackOverflow! I think it is better for you to add your code to the question itself. Just click on edit.

@aaaali, could you move your comments into your question body? It was supposed to be there.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

now i updated my body please do check

Solution:-
Since WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is  deprecated for Android 11 (API level 30) and above, you need to use Media Store API or Scoped Storage.
    const getPermissionAndroid = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
    if (Platform.Version >= 33) {
    // Request permission for managing external storage (Android 11+)
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, // For accessing media files
    {
     title: 'File Download Permission',
     message: 'Your permission is required to save Files to your device',
     buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
     buttonPositive: 'OK',
     },
     );

     if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
     return true;
     } else {
     setIsOpenExport(false); Toast.error(('Permission required'));
     return false;
     }
     }
     else if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
     return true;
     }

    else {
    // For API levels < 33
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
   PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
   {
     title: 'File Download Permission',
     message: 'Your permission is required to save Files to your device',
     buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
     buttonPositive: 'OK',
     },
     );
     if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
     return true;
     } else {
     setIsOpenExport(false); Toast.error(('Permission required'));
     return false;
     }
     }

     } catch (err) { console.log('Error' + err); return false; }
     }, [])

